# How to parse AAAA record RDATA using java

Tags: java, dns

I want to parse the RDATA of a AAAA record response. As a quick 101 intro to DNS responses this is what an `Answer` section from a response looks like(according to [RFC-1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) - mind you the format hasn't changed since it's inception, and most likely won't change any time soon):

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                                               |
/                                               /
/                      NAME                     /
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TYPE                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                     CLASS                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TTL                      |
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                   RDLENGTH                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
/                     RDATA                     /
/                                               /
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

The last section `RDATA` is resource record type specific. So for example a `CNAME` record will have a different format.

According to [RFC-3596](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3596) a AAAA data format is

```
A 128 bit IPv6 address is encoded in the data portion of an AAAA
resource record in network byte order (high-order byte first).
```

I haven't been able to find other RFCs pertaining specifically to AAAA record RDATA format.

Section 2.5 of [RFC-3596](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3596) seems to better define how to parse the RDATA:

```
   An IPv6 address is represented as a name in the IP6.ARPA domain by a
   sequence of nibbles separated by dots with the suffix ".IP6.ARPA".
   The sequence of nibbles is encoded in reverse order, i.e., the
   low-order nibble is encoded first, followed by the next low-order
   nibble and so on.  Each nibble is represented by a hexadecimal digit.
   For example, the reverse lookup domain name corresponding to the
   address

       4321:0:1:2:3:4:567:89ab

   would be

   b.a.9.8.7.6.5.0.4.0.0.0.3.0.0.0.2.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.2.3.4.IP6.ARPA.
```

Putting 2 and 2 together it seems that the `RDATA` is 128 bit long little endian. With that said, I can't figure out HOW exactly to parse this correctly.

Here's my code

```
private AAAARecordData parseRDataForAAAARecord(DataInputStream dataInputStream, int rdLength) throws IOException {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[rdLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < rdLength; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = (byte)(dataInputStream.readByte() & 0xFF);
    }

    String result = HexFormat.of().formatHex(byteArray); // 2a001450400d0807000000000000200e

    // do some more processing here maybe? not sure

    return new AAAARecordData(result);
}
```

And some sample data for `byteArray`

<strike>[42, 0, 20, 80, 64, 13, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 14]</strike>

```
[42, 0, 20, 80, 64, 13, 8, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 14]
```

The output of `parseRDataForAAAARecord` is `2a001450400d0804000000000000200e`

Using wireshark to intercept the request I get

```
// other stuff
Answers
    google.com: type AAAA, class IN, addr 2a00:1450:400d:80a::200e
        Name: google.com
        Type: AAAA (IPv6 Address) (28)
        Class: IN (0x0001)
        Time to live: 270 (4 minutes, 30 seconds)
        Data length: 16
        AAAA Address: 2a00:1450:400d:80a::200e
[Request In: 1]
[Time: 0.019593000 seconds]
```

As you may have guess by now, my result and the wireshark AAAA address are pretty similar. So clearly I'm not doing something correctly somewhere.

I'm fairly certain anything before the processing is correct as it works fine for `A` records and a few other record types.

[image]

Comment: "128 byte long" did you mean *bit*?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I've corrected it.

Comment: So the only difference is that you're getting  7 instead of 10?

Comment: Hmm...you lost me a bit there. Could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: Where does the sample data in `byteArray` come from? Do you expect it to decode to `2a00:1450:400d:80a::200e`?

Comment: The data in `byteArray` comes from a DNS(cloudflare in this case) datagram response which I'm parsing. Yes, I expect it to decode to a IPV6 address. The problem is I don't know what rules to follow in order to decode it(properly).

Comment: I don't see how the output can be `...0804...` when the data is `8, 7`

Comment: Correct, I think I copied the wrong value somehow. I've edited my question with an image and the correct sequence of the bytes.

Comment: That looks OK then, I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: I think I just copied some stuff wrong, not sure. Works fine tbh. Why don't you put that comment as an answer so that I can properly accept it.

Comment: A tip: in similar cases, you can study code of any DNS library and see how they cope with it.

Comment: "Looks OK" wouldn't be a very valuable answer :-)